# NVL for numbers in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to replace null price values by another charge value:
[image]

Result using NVL function:

[image]

Is there any oracle equivalent of NVL for numbers?
Without converting numbers to varchar2?

Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; your query as text (that we can copy-paste and execute and **NOT** as an image which we cannot copy from); and your expected output for that sample data.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you got it wrong. `NVL` doesn't affect **zero** values, but *absence* of value, **NULL**.

Screenshot you posted suggests that

- UNIT_PRICE = 0
- CHARGE_PRICE = 1

so you should have used

```
case when unit_price = 0 then charge_price 
     else unit_price
end
```

Or, if you prefer `decode` in this simple case,

```
decode(unit_price, 0, charge_price, unit_price)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your image does not show any `NULL` values for `unit_price` or `charge_price` so `NVL` will always return the `unit_price`, as the first argument, since it is not `NULL`. If you want to use `NVL` (or something similar like `COALESCE` or a `CASE` expression) for non-`NULL` values then you will need to convert `0` to `NULL`.

However, you have `unit_price` formatted with a right-alignment, which suggests that the column is a number, and `charge_price` formatted with left-alignment suggesting that its data-type is a string. Oracle will convert both sides to have the same data-type so if you want to have them both as numbers then do not store `charge_price` as a string or else use `TO_NUMBER` on the string.

```sql
SELECT unit_price,
       TO_NUMBER(charge_price) AS charge_price,
       CASE
       WHEN unit_price = 0 OR unit_price IS NULL
       THEN TO_NUMBER(charge_price)
       ELSE unit_price
       END
FROM   customer_orders
```